# What is the expected behaviour when using a differential query regarding how many times you may request a page and the page is empty?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

What was the user doing - I am trying to implement Azure AD Groups synchronization in my app as described at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_groups.

However, when implementing the step described under nextLink response, where it says "The response contains a nextLink and another skipToken, indicating there are more groups available. You continue making requests using the nextLink URL until a deltaLink URL is returned in the response.", I am experiencing that a lot of empty page responses containing nextLink are returned by the API before finally receiving one that contains a deltaLink. The fact that the pages are empty is expected since there are no changes in the groups. The largest number I have seen was 15, but it's typically around 4-5 pages.

Is this behavior expected?
Here is an example of this situation, the following is a list of Request-ids and timestamps:

Initial request to /delta
date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:14:32 GMT
request-id: 4ccf6e1e-e151-491c-a24d-b2d8c143ad4a

Request 1 (following nextLink from previous):
date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:14:32 GMT
request-id: a55e2271-1703-47ec-b052-d7169d017dbb

Request 2 (following nextLink from previous):
date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:14:32 GMT
request-id: 4c40e7b2-cd1a-4871-b452-e22f3dc5de03

Request 3 (following nextLink from previous):
date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:14:32 GMT
request-id: aa98732c-8635-45d0-99af-d3289a0c47b6

Request 4 (following nextLink from previous):
date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:14:32 GMT
request-id: cea81ae1-0437-4e96-9fe9-29bc193dffb4

In this case, all requests return an empty list of changes ("values:" []). However, requests 1-3 all return a nextLink and it is only request 4 that finally returns a deltaLink.

Is this the expected behavior?